# Need help for the physical design of a big table with rows populated in 3 stages

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing a special SQL Server table with 1M rows added daily. The table is populated in 3 phases. That means the entity lifecycle has 4 states:

- State 1: Inserts a new row and populates columns 1-15. The rest of columns stay NULL.
- State 2: Updates (populates) columns 16-25
- State 3: Updates (populates) columns 26-40
- State 4: The row can be processed for reporting.

Above requirements imposes the following inefficiencies:

- All of the columns 16-40 must be nullable since they are populated after each row is created.
- Since there are at least 2 sets of NULL columns are pupated (update) after each row is created, there will be many fragmentations – I assume right?

I was thinking to break this entity to 3 tables, however, if I do that then I need to keep join the 3 tables during the reporting. 
Is there any technique or pattern that help me to make this table more efficient?

Answer (score -1):

We had a similar situation where columns 1-3 make up the unique key for the dataset and columns 4-100 were the table data.

Basically, we broke it up into:
1) A table that holds the 3 column unique key as well as an ID column (Date, Identity, etc as necessary) 
2) A table that holds key-value pairs of column name/number and column value and a FK to the ID in table 1.

Table 1

```
ID | Date     | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 
1  | 1/5/2016 | USA  | USD  | TRUE
2  | 1/5/2016 | UK   | GBP  | TRUE
3  | 1/5/2016 | UK   | EUR  | FALSE
4  | 1/6/2016 | USA  | USD  | TRUE
```

Table 2

```
ID | Column_No | Value
1  | 16        | 53
1  | 17        | Greenback
1  | 18        | Chicago
2  | 16        | 1.3
2  | 23        | Leeds
3  | 16        | 2.8
3  | 18        | Manchester
3  | 26        | 643
3  | 33        | MThatcher
3  | 34        | Union Jack
```

There are a lot of things to consider; how your users are querying the data set, how you're getting updates, whether you have to preserve history, etc. This will help you figure out table design and indexes.

This is an over simplified answer, but may point you in the right direction.

Comment: The idea you explained works well when the columns are occasionally used (filled). The requirement here is different. All the row columns are filled. The problem is that they are not populated at the INSERT time and there are subsequent updates. BTW, for the scenario you explained, you should take a look at Sparse Columns.